# Why do random variables exist?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, measurable-functions

We define a random variable to be a measurable function $X$ from a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ to a measurable space $(S,\mathcal{B})$.
Given a probability measure $\mu$ on $S$ we say that $X$ follows the probability law $\mu$ if the pushfoward of $P$ via $X$ is equal to $\mu$ $$X\sim\mu\text{ if and only if. } X_*(P)=\mu.$$
At this point it seems to me that the probability space $\Omega$ is forgotten, and all reasoning are done thinking to their law.

So my question is: *Are there situations where it is relevant to distinguish random variables from their law?*
*If it is just a matter of notation, are there problems that are dealt with significantly better in one formalism with respect to the other?*

Comment: Personally I would say the probability space is foundational and so usually ignored in most applications, though some of the sigma-algebra properties can remain useful later

Comment: You cannot make sense of notions such as independence or covariance unless you see your two variables as functions on the **same** probability space!

Comment: there are many theorems that are easier to state in $\Omega$ instead of $\Bbb R$, by example things related to martingales or just conditional expectation

Comment: Imagine how it would be a pain to describe the strong law of large numbers only using their (joint) probability laws. As random variables represent samples, the notion of r.v. provides a power tool for working with those 'sample values'. As an extreme example, the Wiener measure is just a measure with some strange finite-dimensional distributions, but its sample paths (Brownian paths) are what makes this measure interesting.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot that can be said about a random variable
$$
  X: (\Omega,\mathcal{F},P) \to  (S,\mathcal{B}),
  $$
just by looking at $\mu:=X_*(P)$.  For example, if $S=\mathbb R$, then the expectation $\mathbb E(X)$ may be computed
in terms of $\mu $ as follows,  thanks to the change of variable formula applied to $x = X(ω)$:
$$
  \mathbb E(X) =
  \int_\Omega  X(\omega ) \, dP(\omega ) =
  \int_{\mathbb R} x \, d\mu (x).
  $$
Similar facts hold for the standard deviation and most other important concepts referring to a  SINGLE random
variable.

However, statistical notions that depend of  TWO random variables,  say
$$
  X_1, X_2: \Omega \to  \mathbb R,
  $$
often cannot be expressed in terms of the probability laws $\mu_1:={X_1}_*(P)$ and $\mu_2:={X_2}_*(P)$,  an example being
the covariance
$$
  \text{cov}(X_1,X_2) =  \int_\Omega  \big (X_1(\omega )-\mathbb E(X_1)\big )(X_2(\omega )-\mathbb E(X_2)\big ) \, dP(\omega ).
  $$

A clever way to study   two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$,  as above,  without too much emphasis on the space
$\Omega $, is to  consider the function
$$
  T:\omega \in \Omega \mapsto (X_1(\omega ),X_2(\omega ))\in \mathbb R^2,
  $$
together with the two projections
$$
  \pi _i:(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R^2 \mapsto  x_i \in  \mathbb R.
  $$

Besides the fact that $X_i=\pi _i\circ T$, notice that if   $Q$ is the probability measure on  $\mathbb R^2$ given by
$$
  Q=T_*(P),
  $$
we have that
$$
  {\pi _i}_*(Q) =   {\pi _i}_*(T_*(P)) = (\pi _i\circ T)_*(P) = {X_i}_*(P)=\mu _i.
  $$

This said we may safely replace $(\Omega ,P)$ by $(\mathbb R^2,Q)$,
$$
  \matrix{
    && \kern30pt\mathbb R \cr
    & & \quad \nearrow_{π_1}   \cr
    Ω & \buildrel T \over \longrightarrow & \mathbb R^2\kern 20pt \cr
    & & \quad \searrow^{π_2}   \cr
    && \kern30pt\mathbb R
    }
  $$
while replacing $X_i$ by $\pi _i$, in the sense that any
statistical information one could ask about $X_1$ and $X_2$ can be easily computed in terms of the new random variables  $\pi _1$
and $\pi _2$ by means of the change of variables $(x_1,x_2)=T(\omega )$.

Regarding expectation, for example, we have
$$
  \mathbb E(X_i) =
  \int_\Omega  X_i(\omega ) \, dP(\omega ) =
  \int_{\mathbb R^2} x_i\, dQ(x_1, x_2) =
  \mathbb E(\pi _i).
  $$

Speaking of covariance,  we have
$$
  \text{cov}(X_1,X_2) =
  \int_\Omega  \big (X_1(\omega )-\mathbb E(X_1)\big )(X_2(\omega )-\mathbb E(X_2)\big ) \, dP(\omega ) = $$ $$ =
  \int_{\mathbb R^2} \big (x_1-\mathbb E(\pi _1)\big )(x_2-\mathbb E(\pi _2)\big ) \, dQ(x_1, x_2) =
  \text{cov}(\pi _1,\pi _2).
  $$

Finally, recall that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are said to be *independent* if
$$
  P\big (\{\omega \in \Omega : X_1(\omega )\in A,\ X_2(\omega )\in B\}\big ) = $$ $$ =
  P\big (\{\omega \in \Omega : X_1(\omega )\in A\}\big )\
  P\big (\{\omega \in \Omega : X_2(\omega )\in B\}\big ),
  \tag 1
  $$
for any two Borel sets $A,B\subseteq \mathbb R$.  Notice that the  LHS above  is precisely equal to
$$
  P\big (T^{-1}(A\times B)\big ) = T_*(P)(A\times B) = Q(A\times B),
  $$
while the RHS is
$$
  P\big (X_1^{-1}(A)\big ) \  P\big (X_2^{-1}(B)\big ) =
  {X_1}_*(P)(A)\   {X_2}_*(P)(B) =
  \mu _1(A)\   \mu _1(B).
  $$

Therefore (1) may be expressed as
$$
  Q(A\times B) =   \mu _1(A)\   \mu _1(B),
  $$
which precisely says that $Q$ is the product measure of $\mu _1$ and $\mu _2$.